# Why doesn't Skype appear in the upper panel?

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel, skype

I normally start Skype and it appears in the upper panel and works. But now when I start it, it doesn't appear! But it works like normal. 
Stackapplet is appearing in the panel.

My whitelist:
`['JavaEmbeddedFrame', 'Mumble', 'Wine', 'Skype', 'hp-systray', 'scp-dbus-service', 'jupiter']`

I've tried

- to remove `jupiter`
- to **purge** skype
- to delete the panel and create a new one

This is how it looks right now. all my other applications work except Skype.
[image]

I guess [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/794846/) is not a normal message to get when I type: `skype -version` ?!

Skype version: **2.2.0.35**

Comment: Is it a 1x1 pixel dot now, or really gone? This is a known bug and if you have the single pixel icon carefully right-click it, quit Skype, and when you restart Skype it should be back to normal. More info here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43280/how-can-i-get-the-skype-notification-back-in-the-system-tray

Comment: @TomBrossman it's **gone**

Comment: @fossfreedom edited my question

Comment: Have you recently added an application that would normally show up mnimized in the system tray?  The reason why I ask - I've see some reports of QT apps causing issues when they minimize in Natty...  Perhaps try disabling most/all of the startup apps except for skype and see if this resolve your issue - trial and error, readd each startup app one by one...

Comment: @fossfreedom I will remove Jupiter from my computer to see if it helps...

Comment: do you have skype running from startup applications?  If you do, try removing it and starting skype manually.  What happens if you do `killall -9 "notification-area-applet"`  a couple of times - anything?  Do you have by any chance an emerald base theme or just the standard ambiance/radiance theme?

Comment: @fossfreedom I have the standard 11.04 theme with changed window borders, skype is not and have never been in my startup applications. all other applications that work in that panel show up.


`notification-area-applet: no process found` with the `killall` command

Comment: huh? Have you removed the notification area applet from the panel?

Comment: @fossfreedom ehm, how will I know that?

Comment: @fossfreedom DOH! I added it and now it works. create an answer if you want the rep, if not, I will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype does not use the standard indicator-applet functionality in Natty to show its Icon.

Instead it requires the old Notification-Area-Applet (right click the Panel and "Add To Panel") for it to work correctly.

You can double check that this applet is running by running the following command in a terminal window:

```
killall -9 "notification-area-applet"
```

If it responds with a "notification-area-applet: no process found" error message then the applet is not running (i.e. has not been added to the gnome-panel)