# How to hide Skype icon from Notification Area?

Tags: indicator, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I remove the Skype panel icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7479/can-i-remove-the-skype-panel-icon)

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 with GNOME 2.32.0. I can't find anywhere how to remove an icon from my notification applet on gnome panel. I would like to hide the Skype icon but still have skype running. I know that sometimes it dissapears but it is a result of a glitch. I would like to hide the skype one icon from the notification area. How can I do this?

[image: notification area]