# How do I remove the Skype icon from the system panel?

Tags: unity, panel, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I remove the Skype panel icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7479/can-i-remove-the-skype-panel-icon)

I have been trying for some time to remove the Skype icon in the upper panel in Ubuntu 11.10, but to no avail.  I have went into dconf, went to desktop -> unity -> panel, and I looked to delete 'Skype' from the whitelist.  But Skype isn't in the whitelist!  And it's showing up on the panel!

Something smells fishy here, and I was wondering if anyone had an answer as to

a) how I can actually remove the Skype icon from the gnome panel

and

b) why an icon still show up there if it isn't in the whitelist?

Also, if it's relevant, I use Unity.

EDIT: So, the only solution for this issue is the scorched earth strategy of removing sni-qt?