# How to keep skype-wrapper in messaging menu after closing it?

Tags: 12.04, skype

I am trying to integrate Skype with Ubuntu. I am using [skype wrapper (link to OMG ubuntu)](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/skype-wrapper/) to have it in the messaging menu after turning it on as well as [this solution on ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/149827/145) to remove the icon from the panel.

When I open skype-wrapper, skype sits nicely in the messaging menu only. However, when I completely exit Skype, it isn't in the messaging menu. The question is: **How can I permanently keep skype-wrapper in the messaging menu (so that I can turn it on from there), like I can with empathy and friends?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications` directory holds a list of text files each containing the path to the desktop launcher of the application the text file is named after.

To add Skype-Wrapper, simply write following command (all one line):

`echo "/usr/share/applications/skype-wrapper.desktop" | sudo tee /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/skype-wrapper`

This is, of course, assuming that the Skype-Wrapper launcher is at `/usr/share/applications/skype-wrapper.desktop`.

Logout, log back in and you are set.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong when I tried the same thing, but it worked this time! Thx. I can't award my bounty for another 4 hours, but you'll get it.