# How to remove the Skype panel icon in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, indicator, skype, panel

This question has been answered a couple of times on this site for other versions of Ubuntu, but the proposed solutions no longer work in Ubuntu 13.04. Specifically, I tried the solution described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7479/how-can-i-remove-the-skype-panel-icon-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-earlier/). However, after following the instructions on that link (i.e. creating a Skype AppArmor profile), skype fails to load with the following error message:

`/usr/bin/skype: 8: exec: /usr/lib/skype/skype: Permission denied`.

Strangely, the same `permission denied` error happens if I try `sudo skype`. So is there another way to remove the skype panel indicator in Ubuntu 13.04, preferably without removing sni-qt?

Comment: @WarrenHill Do the techniques there work for 13.04? The OP here says they do not.

Comment: @EliahKagan - have not tried personally but there was an answer here earlier that said it worked