# Ubuntu 14.04 remove app indicator from upside panel

Tags: unity, indicator, skype

I have Skype installed for my Ubuntu 14.04. And I have added it to indicator-messages (com>canonical>indicator>messages). But now I can't find a way to remove Skype icon from unity panel. I tried to add Skype to unity-gtk-module blacklist, but that doesn't help. Is there a way to forbid an application to show it's icon on panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it by:

> `sudo apt-get remove sni-qt sni-qt:i386`

Note that removing `sni-qt` will affect other apps that depend on it (such as dropbox) to show their icons. If you do not want this to happen, there is a detailed work-around posted in [How can I remove the Skype panel icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7479/how-can-i-remove-the-skype-panel-icon)